# Sending Notification from android to other android devices

Tags: android, firebase

I am always getting an error on sending notification from android device in logcat I have tried so many times but nothing getting:

```
{"multicast_id":5162718122421221171,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Here is my android code for sending message I am sending userABC topic in the topic section.

```
public void SendNotification(String Title, String Message){
    NOTIFICATION_TITLE = Title;
    NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = Message;

    JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject notifcationBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        notifcationBody.put("title", NOTIFICATION_TITLE);
        notifcationBody.put("message", NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);

        notification.put("to", TOPIC);
        notification.put("data", notifcationBody);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
    sendNotification(notification);
}

private void sendNotification(JSONObject notification) {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(FCM_API, notification,

    new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());

                }
            },
            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Request error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Didn't work");
                }
            }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Authorization", serverKey);
            params.put("Content-Type", contentType);
            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Here is my FirebaseInstanceIDService.java class

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "mFirebaseIIDService";
private static final String SUBSCRIBE_TO = "userABC";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    /*
      This method is invoked whenever the token refreshes
      OPTIONAL: If you want to send messages to this application instance
      or manage this apps subscriptions on the server side,
      you can send this token to your server.
    */
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    // Once the token is generated, subscribe to topic with the userId
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(SUBSCRIBE_TO);
    Log.i(TAG, "onTokenRefresh completed with token: " + token);
    sendRegistrationToServer(token);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // send token to web service ??
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/IDs");
    // then store your token ID
    ref.push().setValue(token);
}
```

}

Here is my FirebaseMessagingService.java class

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

private final String ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID ="admin_channel";

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Refreshed token: " + token);
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("THIS", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("userABC");
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // send token to web service ??
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/IDs");
    // then store your token ID
    ref.push().setValue(token);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int notificationID = new Random().nextInt(3000);

  /*
    Apps targeting SDK 26 or above (Android O) must implement notification channels and add its notifications
    to at least one of them. Therefore, confirm if version is Oreo or higher, then setup notification channel
  */
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setupChannels(notificationManager);
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this , 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Uri notificationSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    //Set notification color to match your app color template
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build());
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void setupChannels(NotificationManager notificationManager){
    CharSequence adminChannelName = "New notification";
    String adminChannelDescription = "Device to devie notification";

    NotificationChannel adminChannel;
    adminChannel = new NotificationChannel(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID, adminChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    adminChannel.setDescription(adminChannelDescription);
    adminChannel.enableLights(true);
    adminChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
    adminChannel.enableVibration(true);
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(adminChannel);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FirebaseInstanceIdService is **deprecated** now.

So you can change your registration logic as below

**FcmRegistrationManager.java**

```
public class FcmRegistrationManager {

private static final String TAG = "FcmRegistrationManager"

/*This is async call*/
public void registerWithFcm(){
    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                    return;
                }

                // Get new Instance ID token
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();

                Log.d(TAG, msg);
                sendRegistrationToServer(token)

            }
        });

}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // send token to web service ??
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/IDs");
    // then store your token ID
    ref.push().setValue(token);
}

}
```

No change for sendNotification() and FirebaseMessagingService class.
More reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Let me still not working, I will share you working code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer my issue really is i am sending userABC in topics instead of /topics/userABC. And also your suggestion is very good that also helped me. Now I have removed FirebaseInstanceIdService